# Metatrader 4 | No trades to be placed on EA re-initialization

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I have an EA which places a trade - considering all other conditions are met - at the beginning of the candlestick bar & based on the "datetime time[0]`.

Naturally, if I were to reinitialize the EA, the EA would "re-recognise" the conditions and execute another trade. How would I stop that from happening on the `oninit` section of my EA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare global variable `bool initTrade = true;`

and:

```
int OnInit()
 {
   if(OrdersTotal() > 0){
      if(OrderSelect(OrdersTotal()-1, SELECT_BY_POS)){
         if(Minute() == TimeMinute(OrderOpenTime())  && Hour() == TimeHour(OrderOpenTime()) && Day() == TimeDay(OrderOpenTime())){
            initTrade = false;
         }
         if(initTrade){
            //Open init order logic...
         }
      }
   }
 return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
```